# Is this really an abstract class?

Tags: python, abstract-class

Suppose I have a class like so:

```
class Robot:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def some_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError

    # ... and so on; each method simply raises NotImplementedError
```

Is this really an abstract class? The  only part  that seems to resemble an abstract class is the `raise NotImplementedError`.

Am I correct in thinking this way and if so what are the advantages of using an abstract class as opposed to just using inheritance?

[Link to relevant example](http://pastebin.com/g5efFCAC)

Comment: It is not abstract, but it attempts to mimic abstraction.

Comment: @MirroredFate, that is what I thought, I saw it as an easy introduction to how abstract classes work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is not an abstract class as defined in [PEP 3119](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/), but that wasn't always part of Python. Like many things in computer science, it depends. There are many flavors of OO and correspondingly varying definitions of what constitutes an abstract class.

There is certainly an argument that it is a type of abstract class simply because of the `NotImplemented` error. Perhaps more appropriately to Python, it is being *used* as an abstract class (think "duck typing"). This doesn't hold water if you are going by, say, Java's definition of abstract, because it can still be instantiated. However, consider:

```
>>> obj = object()  # This works; just doesn't do much
```

Arguably, `object` is an abstract class in Python if anything is. It was [added to the language](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/) precisely so that built-in objects could subclass it, to make the OO behavior more consistent throughout Python. However, as you can see, it can still be instantiated.

Lastly, you ask "what are the advantages of using an abstract class as opposed to just using inheritance?"

What exactly constitutes "just using inheritance"? Even in subclassing (and ideally fully implementing) abstract classes, we are still using inheritance. The only difference is that abstract base classes provide little in the way of *implementation*, and merely define a *specification* for a type of object, a blueprint for future subclasses.

Lastly, consider what [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html) have to say about `NotImplementedError`:

> exception `NotImplementedError`
>
> This exception is derived from `RuntimeError`. **In user defined base classes, abstract methods should raise this exception** when they require derived classes to override the method.

So this is very much in line with one way Python provides to create abstract classes.

Comment: bad choice of words, "just using inheritance", I should have said just writing all the methods in the base class and just overriding in subclasses if needed.

Comment: It's very much up to the designer. In this case, the intent is to make sure that all subclasses are structured the same way (common subset of methods) but not to specify anything in the way of implementation. The decision still has to be made somewhere (and by someone); this is just a way of transferring control to a different developer.

Comment: So,is the NotImplementedError more of a failsafe to identify when someone is trying to access a method either directly or indirectly that has not been coded?

Comment: `NotImplementedError` is exactly what its name implies: an error raised when an abstract method was not implemented in a subclass. Since the subclass does not provide it, having methods like these in the ancestor class provide a convenient way through inheritance to get this warning. As a developer, you should read this as the original designer saying, _if you want to have a compliant implementation of this, define all of these methods_. As a user, you are within your rights to expect all of these methods to work.

Comment: Surely the new way using "abc" is the best implementation, as on trying to instantiate the class or a subclass you will be warned that the class is an abstract class, where  having one method with a  NotImplementedError will not come to light until there is a call to that method